# Assign variable to solve

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, parametric-functions, variable-definitions, variable

I would like to assign my result from equation. I tried `/.` and `:=` but it gives me empty variable. How can i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to set phi c, as in

```
c = c /. Solve[... , c]
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I have one more question, if i have two variables for example
 {a,b} = {a,b}/. Solve[... , {a,b}] is that correct assignment ?

Comment: Not really, because there may be multiple solutions, for example with `x = x /. Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]` the result is a list of solutions.

Comment: But if am sure that there would be one solution for a and one for b?

Comment: Yes then, that would work.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: More like `{{a,b}} = {a,b}/. Solve[... , {a,b}]` though.

Comment: For example, `{{x, y}} = {x, y} /. Solve[a x + y == 7 && b x - y == 1, {x, y}]`